# Sort ListView on any column

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, listview

The answer to my question came from TaW in a comment.  The example shown in [MSN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319401?wa=wsignin1.0)article works perfect and clears up my issue.  Of course I omitted Step 5 because that work was already done in code I submitted when opening the question.  Thank you TaW

I have a 3 column listview and would like to sort on any column by clicking column header and don't have a clue how to go about it.  All 3 columns are string.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996467.aspx says gives an example but I'm not comprehending.  When I copy and paste that chunk of code into my program I get a syntax error [using the generic type 'system.Collections.Generic.IComparer' requires 1 type arguments] having said that I don't know if I'm on the right track or how to resolve.

```
    private void getlvAMFiles()
    {
        //lvAM.Items.Clear();
        DataView view = new DataView(tblvAttributes);
        DataTable distinct = view.ToTable(true, "DWPhysicalTableName", "DWPhysicalSchemaName");
        if (cbRegion.SelectedIndex < 0) return;
        DataView view1 = new DataView(tblvAttributes);
        DataTable distinctValues = view1.ToTable(true, "dwPhysicalSchemaName","dwPhysicalTableName");
        foreach (DataRow row in distinctValues.Rows) 
        { ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row["dwPhysicalSchemaName"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(row["dwPhysicalTableName"].ToString().Substring(row["dwPhysicalTableName"].ToString().LastIndexOf("F") + 1)); 
            item.SubItems.Add(row["dwPhysicalTableName"].ToString());
            lvAM.Items.Add(item); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: On another blog it said that it should be IComparer<T> not IComparer in the example I referenced in the MSDN link.  So the error is gone but I still don't know how to use it.

Comment: For unbound ListViews this [MSDN article](See [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319401)!) looks harder than it really is. But for a databound ListView you should be able to sort the DataView, no?

Comment: You didn't propose this as an answer but it is.  Cleared everything up and works great.

Comment: If you solved it by sorting the DataView you may want to write it as your own answer. If you do include the click and the sort routine! I'll check to see if it deserves an upvote ;-)

Comment: I solved it by following the instructions in the link you provided.  The only difference was step 5 where I populate the listview from datatable as shown in code I submitted and I used the properties to set columns/item definitions.

Comment: Cool! You still could write a little about this, maybe in an edit to the question..